# remove columns based on values in R

Tags: r

let's say there is a dataframe like this

```
    set.seed(1)    
    var1<-sample(-100:1000,10,replace=T)
    var2<-sample(-20:-2,10,replace=T)
    var3<-sample(-1:20,10,replace=T)
    var4<-sample(-12:16,10,replace=T)
    var5<-sample(0:200,10,replace=T)
    df<-data.frame(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5)
    df
```

I need only columns that have values that are <= -2 or >=2.

Comment: can you please tell us of a number that is less than -2 and greater than 2?? There is no such a number so its either less than -2 or greater than 2 but not less than -2 and greater than 2

Comment: `Filter(\(x) all( x < -2 | x > 2), df)`

Comment: `df[apply(df< -2 | df>2, 2, all)]`

Comment: `df[sapply(df, \(x)all( x < -2 | x > 2))]`

Comment: `df %>% select(where(~all( .x < -2 | .x > 2)))`

Comment: `df %>% select_if(~all( .x < -2 | .x > 2))`

Comment: `df %>% keep(~all( .x < -2 | .x > 2))`

Comment: @Onyambu. These comments should go into an answer, not several comments, IMO.

Comment: right. I meant the values in the column all should be either less than -2 or greater than 2.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use a data.frame method, but it looks like a matrix may be a better storage solution.

```
df <- dt[sapply(dt, function(x){any(abs(x) > 2)})]
```